# 3.95 MCU Friend Arduino TFT LCD flickering

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

I got the 3.95" LCD from aliexpress which uses IL9488. I used the [MCUFRIEND_kbv](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=366304.msg2524865#msg2524865) library. I am using an Arduino Mega as I need other GPIO to be used for other purposes. I can't use the Uno because of this limitation.

I have other modules like the DS3231, and ESP8266 connected to the Mega and this 3.95" LCD connected as well. ESP8266 is powered separately using a 12-5V converted supply. The Mega is powered using another source. The normal graphics test is working in the LCD. I am able to make it work with the Nano, Uno and Mega. Even for the Mega I am able to write customized messages.

What I intend to do is to update the time in the LCD which is received from the DS3231. It updates the LCD but I see a flickering issue here.

Every update (LCD display function is from the loop which sets the text when there is a second/time/hour difference in the time) seems like it draining more current as the one of the LED connected to Mega dims, the Rx/Tx LEDs also dim.

I am able to get the LCD refreshed but it shows a flickering. I powered the LCD 3.3V and 5V using another separate source but still the small flickering continues.

Moreover all these time I was connected to the Mega through the USB from the laptop. Once I unplug the USB, LCD starts and shows some update and again become white. This continues and an not able to see anything on LCD there after.

I am not sure why only when the Mega is connected to USB this LCD works and that too flickering but once the USB is removed the LCD is not working at all.

Can someone please do help me in this ?

Comment: Are you referring to an LCD on a shield, like [LCD Display Module TFT 3.95 inch TFT LCD screen for Arduino UNO R3 Board](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-LCD-Display-Module-TFT-3-95-inch-TFT-LCD-screen-for-Arduino-UNO-R3/1995671772.html)?  Do you have a way to measure the current draw?

Comment: Yes, the same thing only I have. But I am supplying a separate 2amp supply to the LCD .And all the grounds are set together.Not sure whether that gonna be an issue. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you have a schematic or picture of your connections?

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong with this LCD board. This is because in my case the display works sometimes perfectly with the ILI9481 driver but sometimes something hangs and the display starts to flicker. It looks like a chip charging problem. Anyway I solved the flickering problem by tuning the ILI9488 registers. Simply you have to change the `initlcd.h` for ILI9481 driver in UTFT library.

```
enter code here

case ILI9481:


LCD_Write_COM(0x11);
delay(70);

LCD_Write_COM(0x38);//Idle Mode OFF
LCD_Write_COM(0x13);//Normal mode

LCD_Write_COM(0x36); // Memory Access Control  crucial
LCD_Write_DATA(0x0A);



LCD_Write_COM(0x55);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x22);//High enhancment of CE ratio



LCD_Write_COM(0xB1);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x70);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x10);

LCD_Write_COM(0xB4);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x10);

LCD_Write_COM(0xB5);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x12);

LCD_Write_COM(0xB6);        // Display Function Control
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x21);       // 0x42 = Rotate display 180 deg.
LCD_Write_DATA(0x3B);


LCD_Write_COM(0xC0);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x1F);//0X1F
LCD_Write_DATA(0x01);//0X10

LCD_Write_COM(0xC1);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x10);

LCD_Write_COM(0xC2);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);//0X44 lower better
LCD_Write_COM(0xC4);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);//0X10

LCD_Write_COM(0xC5);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);//0X10
LCD_Write_DATA(0x80);//optimum
LCD_Write_DATA(0x80);//0X10


LCD_Write_COM(0x3A);//Interface Pixel Format
LCD_Write_DATA(0x55);

LCD_Write_COM(0x2A);//Column Address Set
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x01);
LCD_Write_DATA(0xDF);//320

LCD_Write_COM(0x2B);//Page Address Set
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x00);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x01);
LCD_Write_DATA(0x3F);//480


delay(60);

LCD_Write_COM(0x29);//Display ON
delay(30);

LCD_Write_COM(0x2C);//Memory Write
delay(30);
break;
```